# android viewpager with media player, occasional crash

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, media-player, android-viewpager

I made a Viewpager that uses 3 different layouts. A Listview index page, followed by alternating pages of picture and text. The XMLs are all LinearLayouts containing an Imageview, Listview, or Textview as appropriate. The text pages also may have a MediaPlayer in them (if there is a reference to a sound in the database).

My problem is that I get an occasional crash when scrolling (rapidly) back and forth through the pages.  At this point I only have 5 pages total, and only 1 has a sound.  Eventually there will be 21 pages and 10 of those will have sounds.  I'm guessing there's some untidiness where I'm not doing appropriate cleanup of memory?

Where should I be looking to find the cause and fix it? There doesn't seem to be an onDestroy method for MediaPlayer. What is the best practice for allocating/releasing media resources (keeping in mind that Viewpager seems to hold 3 pages in memory at any given moment).

edit to add more info: The page with the sound file is the 3rd one (i.e. in the middle), so it probably has something to do with recreating the view after it has dropped out of memory when swiping to the last or first page. I do not have to play the sound in order to get the error.  I think I may have narrowed it down some - after swiping 41 times going from page 1 to 5 and back (which means  it's the 11th time the page is recreated), it dies. There is another part of this app which is set up identically (just a different database table) and that *also* counts toward the 41, i.e. if I swipe 40 times in this part of the app, then go to the other part of the app, it's the fatal 41 and it will die with the same type of error.

ps/please be kind, I have been working with Android for only 3 months and did not know Java or much about OOP before this.

Code at the error is mp.setOnCompletionListener:

```
public void setSoundUrl(Uri path) throws IOException {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getContext(), path);
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    updateProgressBar();
}
```

Prior error is audioPlayer.setSoundUrl(path);

```
private AudioPlayer setUpSound(LinearLayout ll, Matcher matcher) {
    AudioPlayer audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer(ll.getContext(),attrs);
    int soundRes = getResources().getIdentifier(matcher.group(2).trim(), "raw", "com.example");
    Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example/" + soundRes);
    try {
        audioPlayer.setSoundUrl(path);
        audioPlayer.setTitle(matcher.group(3).trim());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return audioPlayer;
}
```

Stack trace:

```
12-20 15:40:02.330: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12321): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.AudioPlayer.setSoundUrl(AudioPlayer.java:78)
    at com.example.ShowBirdText.setUpSound(ShowBirdText.java:127)
    at com.example.ShowBirdText.onCreateView(ShowBirdText.java:73)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1264)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:672)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1012)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:881)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:237)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is the path passed to `setSoundUrl` ever null or an invalid path?

Comment: No. The TextViews are dynamically created for the text pages. If there's a reference to a sound in the database, it'll create a MediaPlayer for it.  There is only 1 sound right now and it definitely works. It's only after swiping back and forth a lot that the error happens.  However, I admit there is not yet any error checking for an invalid resource name.

Comment: Is there a `release()` method?

Comment: I figured out the problem. There was a release() method, but it was releasing the wrong object variable, a leftover from before I'd implemented a MediaPlayer with a progress bar and the little bells and whistles. Very silly of me.